# Counting Operation in Automatic Differentation - Forward vs Backward Mode

Tags: derivatives

I've got a question concerning counting operations in Forward & Reverse Mode. Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

The Primal Trace contains $n$ operations, each node has one operation done, therefore $n$ nodes have $n$ operations done. I'm struggling to find a general definition for operations done for the Derivative Trace in Forward Mode and the Reverse Adjoint Trace in Reverse Mode.

Is there even a way to describe the general amount of operations done? I've tried to think of an upper barrier in Reverse Mode: Each node in the Adjoint Trace can contain a maximum of 3 operations, thus, in general there is a maximum of 3$n$ operations?